# How Gtk library use graphic card

Tags: gtk

I write a billiard game with C language and GTK library but some people told me that this library use CPU not graphic card .
i have intel graphic card on my fedora . How can i say to my program to use intel ?

thanks

Comment: The easiest way to do that is OpenGL, but OpenGL is not so easy...

Answer (score 3):

GTK uses the graphics card, obviously, otherwise you would not be able to display anything. GTK uses Cairo, which will use fast paths for 2D rendering.

what Cairo, and thus GTK, does not use is hardware acceleration for blending and compositing of surfaces.

if you need hardware acceleration and you wish to use a portable API for that, you can use OpenGL.integrating OpenGL with GTK is not entirely trivial, though.

if all you're using are 2D surfaces, you could use the Clutter scene graph.

or you could skip GTK entirely, and use SDL, which is a portable library for games that takes care of the windowing system set up, and just gives you a surface to draw on. you'll have to write your own GUI elements, and you can use OpenGL to render your game.

Comment: Might want to update that answer for Gtk 4. The question may be really old, but it still shows up prominently in search results.